# jquery mobile textarea line breaks dissapears

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

text in textarea is:

```
example
line 2 textam
```

with some code like this I add something to text (or just get current text and reinsert it to textarea):

```
    var curtxt= $('#editor').text();
    $('#editor').text(curtxt);
```

now text is like:

```
example line 2 textam
```

and line breaks removed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use val() instead of text()

```
var curtxt= $('#editor').val();
$('#editor').val(curtxt);
```